# Se puede llamar a una class PreferenceFragment antes de ejecutar un metodo?

Tags: android

En mi aplicación antes de ejecutar el Intent que está dentro de onOptionsItemSelected  necesito leer los valores de ListPreference, para ello estoy usando MyPreferenceFragment, pero cuando trato de ejecutar esto dentro de onOptionsItemSelected obtengo error, alguien me podria decir como solucionar esto

Aqui esta mi codigo:

```
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener
        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue( stringValue );
            preference.setSummary(index >= 0 ? listPreference.getEntries()[index] : null );
        }else {
            preference.setSummary( stringValue );
        }
        return true;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    setupActionBar();

    //Recibiendo datos por Intent desde MainActivity
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    mconfigbaudrate = bundle.getString("mconfigbaudratex");
    mconfigdatabit = bundle.getString("mconfigdatabitx");
    mconfigbitstop = bundle.getString("mconfigbitstopx");

}


private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
         actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( true );
    }
}

private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {

    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener( sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener );
    sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange( preference,PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences( preference.getContext() )
            .getString( preference.getKey(), "" ) );
}

public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_setup_com);

        setHasOptionsMenu( true );

        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue( findPreference( "config_baud_rate" ) );
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue( findPreference( "config_data_bit" ) );
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue( findPreference( "config_bit_stop" ) );

       // Leendo parametros de ListPreference para enviarlos por Intent a MainActivity
        ListPreference SPconfigbaudrate2 = (ListPreference) findPreference("config_baud_rate");
        mconfigbaudrate = SPconfigbaudrate2.getValue();

        ListPreference SPconfigdatabit2 = (ListPreference) findPreference("config_data_bit");
        mconfigdatabit = SPconfigdatabit2.getValue();

        ListPreference SPconfigbitstop2 = (ListPreference) findPreference("config_bit_stop");
        mconfigbitstop = SPconfigbitstop2.getValue();

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {

        //Enviando datos por Intent a MainActivity
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        intent2.putExtra("mconfigbaudratex",mconfigbaudrate);
        intent2.putExtra("mconfigdatabitx",mconfigdatabit);
        intent2.putExtra("mconfigbitstopx", mconfigbitstop);

        startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );
}
```

}

Comment: si puedes compartir el error que te aparece seria de ayuda

Comment: solo que si los datos los tienes en preferences, bien puedes buscarlos en el oncreate de la actividad MainActivity